# Display all values from JavaStript result

Tags: javascript, json

I have this Javascript:

```
function sendRequest_for_Get_Popular() {
  movies_ArrayDataModel.clear();
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key="
          + config.API_KEY + "&language=en-US&page=1";

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {

        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        var lenght = response.results.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
          var results = response.results[i];
          var image = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200/";

          // ========== ========== ==========
          test.text = results.title;
          // ========== ========== ==========
        }
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  xhr.send();
}
```

And this JSON file:

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "total_results": 2,
  "total_pages": 1,
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 475557,
      "title": "Joker",
    },
    {
      "id": 420809,
      "title": "Maleficent: Mistress of Evil",
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to write all `"title"` values ​​in the `"test"` field.
For example, in this format: "Joker, Maleficent: Mistress of Evil"

Now I only get the value of the last `"title"`.
Example: "Maleficent: Mistress of Evil"

Thank you.

Comment: you are overwriting the test.title every iteration, you need to append it rather then overwriting every time thats why you get the last entry. You can put a += in the test. title like (test.Title += results.Title), also make sure to empthy the result before calling the api again as that would just keep on adding the same data over and over again on every api call

Comment: `test.text += results.title;`

Answer (score 0):

There are some informations missing:

How do you use for example the "test" variable - where is it iniziliazed as what?
I would also highly recommend not using these types of generic names. 
One solution for this open asked question:

```
let movies = [];
function sendRequest_for_Get_Popular() {
        ...
        for(let entry of response.results){
          var image = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200/";
          let movie = {"text": entry.title};
          movies.push(movie);
        }
        ...
}
```

Or if you want a string concatination:

```
let movies = {"text": ""};
function sendRequest_for_Get_Popular() {
        ...
        movies.text = response.results.map(a=>a.title).join(',');
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overwriting the `test.text` in each iteration, append the `titles` in each iteration like this.

```
function sendRequest_for_Get_Popular() {
  movies_ArrayDataModel.clear();
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key="
          + config.API_KEY + "&language=en-US&page=1";

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {

        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        var lenght = response.results.length;
        test.text = ''; // initializing the text as blank string here
        for (var i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
          var results = response.results[i];
          var image = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200/";

          // ========== ========== ==========
          test.text += results.title + ', ';
          // ========== ========== ==========
        }
        test.text.replace(/(^,)|(,$)/g, ""); // trimming trailing ','
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  xhr.send();
}
```

**Or even simpler, you can replace your loop with a map and then create a comma separated string from that:**

```
    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    test.text = response.results
                 .map( r => r.title ).join(',');
```

**Or using `reduce`:**

```
var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

test.text = response.results
                 .reduce( (a, r) => a + r.title + ',', '' )
                 .replace(/,$/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same variable each time, so you are overwriting its value.
You can try different approaches to get what you want to achieve.
I would use a map function but a for loop can work either.

```js
// using a for loop

test.text = ''
for (var i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
  var results = response.results[i];
  var image = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200/";

  // ========== ========== ==========
  if (test.text === '') {
    test.text = results.title;
  } else {
    test.text = ', ' + results.title;
  }
  // ========== ========== ==========
}

// using a map function
var titles = response.results.map(function (result) {
  return result.title
})
test.text = titles.join(', ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for your help. I used:

```
test.text += results.title + ", ";
```